# how to divide one matrix into two matrices in python?

Tags: python, matrix

I have one matrix as A. size of A is 8*8.

```
A= [[ 0.  1.  0.  1.  1.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  1. -1.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  1.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
[-1.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

I want to divide A to two matrices (for example P, N) that:

1- matrix P is only contain values "1" of matrix A.

2- matrix N  is only contain values "-1" of matrix A.

3- the size of matrix P and matrix N are 8*8  and  (matrix A =matrix P + matrix N).

I would be very grateful if you guide me.

Answer (score 1):

```
from copy import deepcopy

# make copies of the original
P = deepcopy(A)
N = deepcopy(A)

# in P, keep only +1 
for i, row in enumerate(P):
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        if val != 1:
              P[i][j] = 0

# in N, keep only -1
for i, row in enumerate(N):
    for j, val in enumerate(row):
        if val != -1:
              P[i][j] = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using list comprehensions:

```
A = [[ 0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  1],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  1],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
     [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
     [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]]

P  = [ [max(0,v) for v in line] for line in A]
N  = [ [min(0,v) for v in line] for line in A]

for line in P: print(line)
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for line in N: print(line)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You can add N and P together like this:

```
NP = [ [n+p for n,p in zip(lineN,lineP)] for lineN,lineP in zip(N,P) ]

NP == A # True

for line in NP: print(line)
[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

*Note: You may also want to look into the numpy module.  It does these kinds of things much faster and more elegantly.*

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array( [[ 0,  1,  0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  0],
               [ 0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
               [ 0,  0,  0,  1, -1,  0,  0,  0],
               [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  1],
               [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, -1,  1],
               [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0],
               [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1],
               [-1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]])
P = np.maximum(0,A)
N = np.minimum(0,A)

print(P)
[[0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

print(N)
[[ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]
 [-1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Adding numpy arrays (matrices) together is like adding regular scalar variables:

```
print(P+N)
[[ 0  1  0  1  1  1  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  1 -1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0 -1  1]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0]
 [ 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1]
 [-1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
n = len(A[0]) # n = 8
# generate matrix 
N = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]
P = [[0]*n for i in range(n)]

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if A[i][j] == 1:
            P[i][j] = 1
        elif A[i][j] == -1:
            N[i][j] = -1
```

output:

```
print (P)
print (N)

[[0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]


[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
[-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```